# Need module to accept the timestamp from command line

Tags: perl, command-line

I need a module to accept the following timestamp from command line in Perl.

```
        2010/11/29 09:39:57
```

I have used the `Getopt::Long` module to accept the command line options. But it doesn't accept the full 
timestamp from command line. It is accepting only date value(2010/11/29) not accepting the time value(09:39:57).

If anyone know the module to solve this issue, kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding quotes around the date "2010/11/29 09:39:57"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put quotes around the timestamp. It should work fine with `Getopt::Long`

```
./script.pl -t '2010/11/29 09:39:57'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want them to be separate arguments, you could do something like this:

```
GetOptions('date=s{2}' => \@date);
my ($day, $time) = @date;
```